# access name of the input from Spring form validator

Tags: spring, forms, validation

I have simple form for user registering. This form has field *"age"* which is **integer**. I have created form Validator to validate all inputs. Now I have the problem with "age". If user inputs string in this field (instead of integer), Validator just says that there is *TypeMismatch* and  *result.hasErrors()* returns **true**. But I dont know how to access the name of the field to pass error back to the JSP page with appropriate error. I was only able to access name of my form with:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
            for( ObjectError error: result.getFieldErrors()) {
                System.out.println(error.getObjectName());//returns form name not problematic field
            }
}
```

So my question: how to access field name (specific input name) within Validator to bind error to specific input? I need it to send something to user saying he is wring with **"age"**.

Comment: Why do you need this? There are error codes registered one of the is like `formname.field.TypeMismatch` (or was it the other way around). Basically what you want is already supported out of the box with error messages/binding so not sure why you are trying to work around this.

Comment: See edited question. I want to send something back to user. Like "You enterred wrong age". But I can not catch the condition within Validator. I mean I want to cathc somehow condition: field age has Mismatch and send specific error to specific input field.

Comment: As stated that is already supported by default and hence I wonder why you are reinventing the wheel and work around the framework instead of with the framework.

Comment: Probably I just can not find the way this code: formname.field.TypeMismatch is caught(( Internet is full of examples but all with wrong input with the same type, not with wrong type((

Comment: Can you tell me how can I catch this error? In property file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with the framework not against the framework (see also [Errors Tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-formtaglib-errorstag) in the reference guide.).

First create a properties file containing the error codes you need. How the error codes are generated is defined in the [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html). Basically it does the following

> For example, in case of code "typeMismatch", object name "user", field "age":
>
> 1. try "typeMismatch.user.age"
> 2. try "typeMismatch.age"
> 3. try "typeMismatch.int"
> 4. try "typeMismatch"

Now assuming your model is named user add the following to the properties file (assume it is named `messages.properties`.).

```
typeMismatch.user.age=Entered value is not a valid age. 
typeMismatch.int=Entered value is not an integer.
```

Now remove the code you have in your controller (leave the check for `hasError` as you probably want to re-render the page).

Define a `MessageSource` in your configuration for the `DispatcherServlet` (if you don't already have).

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="baseName" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

Now in your JSP simply add `<form:errors path="*" />` at the top and presto you will have the error in your page. Added bonus you can take into account the users language if you want.

If you want to show the errors next to the field you might want to do something like this.

```
<div>
    <div><label for="age">Age</label></div>
    <div><form:input path="age" id="age" /></div>
    <div><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error" /></div>
</div>
```

Now the error is rendered after the field.

There is no need to mess around with those things yourself.